# In every website I make, I have some page width problems

Tags: html, css, width

Basically, I'm having this happen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/el5zH.png

I can scroll over to farther than I want the page to go. There's nothing in the code specifying a page width, so is there anything I can add? Maybe to the body{} tag in the CSS? Or Metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

That should start to solve your problems.